# Pronunciation of CH in zunächst

Tags: pronunciation

According to https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/ujf/blog/German_ch.html, CHS is usually pronounced as the English X (which is equivalent to /ks/ in IPA), except when the S is added a suffix (e.g. weichste). However, https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zun%C3%A4chst says that the the standard pronunciation of "zunächst" is /tsuˈnɛːçst/ . That's also what I hear at 3:45 minutes in  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vurT-aC0To4 .

On the other hand, I clearly hear CH pronounced in "wächst" as /k/ in https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/w%C3%A4chst .

Are these inconsistencies in pronunciation of the CH digraph due to regional differences?

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: zunächst is zu+nah+st; the s comes from the superlative suffix *-st*.

Somewhere in the more recent history of German, all combinations of CH + S *inside* words came to be pronounced X. So if CHS is part of a single morpheme it is always pronounced X. Morphemes are indivisible units inside of words, e.g. wächst is "wachs" from "wachsen" plus the "-st" ending.
In *wächst*, CHS is part of the morpheme from "wachsen", so it is pronounced with X. It is just the rule that the suffix "-st" does not create double s.

As you already noted, suffixes usually don't trigger this. But in the superlative suffix "-st" both pronunciations are possible, in words like "höchsten", "nächsten", "zunächst". "zunächst" can then be pronounced as /tsuˈnɛːkst/. For "höchsten", [ˈhøːçstn̩] and [ˈhøːkstn̩] are listed, while my personal pronunciation is almost [ˈhøːstn̩].

Comment: Ich behaupte das ist sehr Regions-/Akzentabhängig. Kein Deutschschweiz würde chs als x aussprechen sondern immer als chs.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that there are regional differences.

The pronunciation of the digraph *»ch«* before *»s«* is usually [k].

- sechs = [zɛks], [sɛks]
- Dachs = [daks]
- Fuchs = [fʊks]
- Luchs = [lʊks]
- Buchs = [bʊks]
- Wachs = [vaks]
- wachsen = [ˈvaksn̩] (to grow, but also to wax-polish)
- wechseln = [ˈvɛksl̩n]
- Achse = [ˈaksə]
- Achsel = [ˈaksl̩]
- Sachse =  [ˈzaksə]
- Sachsen = [ˈzaksn̩]

But sometimes the *»s«* after *»ch«* exists because the *»s«* is part of an ending that is not there in the stem of the word, because it was added for grammatical reasons (derivational and inflectional affixes)

- durch → durchs = [dʊʁçs] (Hans robbte durchs Gebüsch.)
- möglich → möglichst = [ˈmøːklɪçst] (Bitte gib möglichst wenig Geld aus.)
- hoch → höchst = [høːçst] (Das ist höchst merkwürdig.)
- weich → weichste = [ˈvaɪ̯çstə] (Er aß die weichste Birne.)
- nah → nächst [ˈnɛːçst] (In der Galerie nächst St. Stephan hängen neue Bilder.)
- nah → demnächst [ˌdeːmˈnɛːçst] (Er wird uns demnächst besuchen.)
- nah → zunächst [t͡suˈnɛːçst] (Ich möchte zunächst den gestrigen Vorfall besprechen.)

But when the *»s«* is already part of the stem, and only a *»t«* is added as affix, then the [k]-pronunciation of *»ch«* in the stem is not changed:

- wachsen → wächst [vɛkst] (Die Blume wächst.)
- wachsen → wachst [vakst] (Hans wachst seine Skier.)
- sechs = sechst [zɛkst] (Sie sind zu sechst hier.)
- sechs = sechste [ˈzɛkstə] (Sie geht in die sechste Klasse.)

---

Note that there are some native German speakers who consider [ç] to be the correct pronunciation, even in the cases where I have given [k]. Especially in the case of the word *»sechs«* ([sɛks] in southern regions, such as Austria, [zɛks] in central and northern regions), which has the same pronunciation as *»Sex«*. So, to avoid any ambiguity, some people pronounce *»sechs«* as [sɛçs] or [zɛçs]. So be prepared to hear this version from time to time.

Comment: Isn't the pronunciation of "wachst" in Hans wachst seine Skier" /vakst/ ? Also, it's a little confusing that you say there are no regional differences, but in the end you say there are.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista: the only regional difference I see mentioned in this answer is the pronunciation of the initial consonant of sechs, which is not what your question is about.

Comment: @sumelic The pronunciation of "ch" in that word was also discussed.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista: Thank you for pointing out the mistake in the pronunciation of *»wachst«*. I have corrected it. Your question referred to the pronunciation of *»ch«* before *»s«,* and I don't think there are regional differences in that. But of course there are many other regional differences in pronunciation in other areas, such as the *»s«* at the beginning of words. The words *»sechs«* and *»Sex«* begin with such an *»s«*, so regional ...

Comment: ... differences manifest in this consonant, but that wasn't what you were asking about. The pronunciation of *»ch«* in *»sechs«* is still not subject to regional differences.